# multiple checkboxes with paging in php without using javascript and jquery

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox, paging

Good day, I have an HTML table and I use paging on it so that only a certain amount of items is shown. The problem is that I need to have multiple selections with checkboxes and that works for a single page but I need that to work between pages. So for example on page 1 you choose 3 items and in the next page you choose 5 items and when GET happens I need to have all those items in one place so that I can store them in a variable.

```
<?php
include("connect.php");     //database connection file
$limit = 7;
if ( isset($_GET['page']) ) {
    $page_no = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    $page_no = 1;
}
$start_from = ($page_no-1)*$limit;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM emp_info LIMIT $start_from,$limit ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn , $sql);
?>

<form method="GET" action="project.php?name=<?php echo
$data['name']; ?>">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>employee information:</h2>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>EmpId</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            <?php
            $info = "SELECT * FROM emp_info LIMIT $start_from,$limit ";
            //query to select the data from database
            $query = mysqli_query ($conn , $info);
            while ( $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($query) )
            {       //query to fetch the data
                $_SESSION['emp_name']=$data['name'];
                ?>  <tr>
                <td><?php echo $data['emp_id'];?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="project.php?id=<?php echo $data['emp_id'];?>&name=<?php echo $data['name']; ?>"> 
                        <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?php echo $data['name'];?>"> 
                    </a> <?php echo $data['name'];?>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $data['email'];?></td>

            </tr>
            <?php           }
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <ul class="pagination">
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM emp_info";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn , $sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            $total_records = $row[0];
            // Number of pages required. 
            $total_pages = ceil($total_records /
                $limit);
            $pagLink = "";
            for ( $i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
                if ( $i == $page_no) {
                    $pagLink .= "<p>Pages:</p><li class='active'><a href='datatable.php?id=" . $data['emp_id'] .
                        "&page=" . $i ."'>". $i ."</a></li>";

                } else  {
                    $pagLink .= "<li><a href='datatable.php?page=". $i ."'>". $i ."</a></li>";
                }
            };
            echo $pagLink;
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    &nbsp; <button type="submit" formaction="project.php"
                   name="select_proj">Select Project</button>
    &nbsp; <button type="submit"
                   formaction="addnewproj.php"  name="add_proj">Add New
        Project</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why w/o js and jQuery?

Comment: because i am very new in php and don't know how to code in js and jquery

Comment: You need data persistence over time. Or, in other words, something like [sessions](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-sessions-and-session-variables-in-php--cms-31839). You can store data in a session and that data will be available on the next page load by the same client.

Comment: can you elaborate using my code.i dont understand how to do that.

Comment: I appreciate that this is a new topic for you, but learning new things is what programmers do on a daily basis. Even if the code was given to you, without understanding it you will immediately get stuck again at the next problem you encounter. Yes, learning about sessions takes time. But learning is fun! You can read [the article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-sessions-and-session-variables-in-php--cms-31839) I gave you the link to, or find one yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reseaching abit of Javascript and more specificly aJax to solve this issue.
You need somewhere to store the information that has been selected in order to use it somewhere else.